# setting the height of the parent according to the highest child element, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a layout, which basically contains a

```
<div class="line" id="#">
<div class="summary">
Some Text
</div>
<div class="summary">
Some
</div>
<div class="summary">
Some long text
</div>
</div>
```

I want, using jQuery, to expand the height of the `<div class="line">` according to the highest child element, I tried fiddling with:

```
$(".line").attr("id", function()
while ($(this).next().length > 0)
{
ac = $(this).children(".summary").outerHeight();
a = $(this).children(".summary").next().outerHeight();

if (a > ac)
{
a = ac;
}
}
$(this).css("height", a + "px");
});
```

and no success, what selectors I need to use, and how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Do you mean highest element, or the largest (height-wise) element?

Comment: @headshota yes, they're floated. @nexxeus largest (height-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if indeed the summary divs are columns in a 3 column layout by applying a `float:left` on them, you could wrap the container nicely around all three by just adding an extra div and style it with `clear:both`

So your html would look like this:

```
<div class="line" id="#">
  <div class="summary">
    Some Text
  </div>
  <div class="summary">
    Some
  </div>
  <div class="summary">
    Some long text
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Jules, doooh! this isn't a 3 column layout, but it did the job.

Comment: @Itai Sagi. nice to hear. A better way to deal whit is (which i always use, cause i use floating columns a lot) is to declare a class in your css file like this `.clearboth {clear:both;}` and then you can simply use a div whit `class="clearboth"` everytime you want to clear all floating behavior

Comment: How do you do this in the case of a list that doesn't tolerate empty `<li>`'s (like a slideshow). You can't just put an empty div in your `<ul>` element but outside any <li> can you? And if you add `<li style="clear:both"></li>`your slideshow shows an empty entry..

Comment: @Shawn, You could just wrap it up like this:`<div class="wrap"><ul class="slideshow"><li></li><li></li></ul><div class="clearboth"></div></div>` then the div.wrap will nicely wrap around the list, so you can define borders or background-colors or whatever to it.